# Optimizing Google AppScript URL request loop

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, optimization

My Google Sheet has become more of a database with 18k rows and my loop scripts are timing out after about 500 rows.  I need help optimizing my script to reducing the runtime and hopefully get all my calls done in a timely manner.

I have 2 sheets.  One sheet holds about 40 API Keys and the other sheet is where the retrieved data is being written.  The website I am calling the data from with the Keys has a 100 request per key per minute hard limit.  To ensure I'm not hitting this hard limit I'm only making 50 calls per Key.

My script is very slow and only returns ~500 rows of data in the execution time limit of ~5 minutes.  Below is the script I am currently using.  This project is about the pinnacle of my coding prowess so if you do respond can you explain it like I'm 5?

```
function GetLastAction1() {
      
  //Get API from spreadsheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Target List - Stats'), true);
  var Targetsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('targetsheet');
  var ApiSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('apisheet');
  var ApiTab = ApiSheet.getSheetByName('API-Stats');
  var TargetTab = Targetsheet.getSheetByName('Target List - Stats');
  var Apilength = ApiTab.getLastRow();
  var ApiCounter =2;
  var StartRow =2;
   
  for (ApiCounter; ApiCounter<Apilength;ApiCounter++){
    var api = ApiTab.getRange(ApiCounter,3).getValue();
    for (var x=0;x<=50;x++){
      var id = TargetTab.getRange(StartRow,15).getValue();
  

        // Call the website API
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.website.com/user/"+id+"?selections=profile&key="+api );

        // Parse the JSON reply
        var json = response.getContentText();
        var data = JSON.parse(json);
        
        //Get Last Action and Write Data
        console.log(data.last_action)
        var ActionTime = data.last_action.timestamp;
        lastAction = new Date(ActionTime*1000);
        lastAction = Utilities.formatDate(lastAction, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        TargetTab.getRange(StartRow,8).setValue(lastAction); 
        StartRow++   
    }
    }
};
```

I thought of creating multiple hard starting and stopping points, but quickly realized I'd need about 40 versions to complete the whole sheet which isn't practical.  Also after searching for similar problems/solutions here I didn't see anything that I understood or that looked like it might apply to my situation.

Comment: Your using getValue()/setValue() known to affect performance consider using getValues()/setValues() as [shown here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: Try getting all of the data in one fetch and then work on the data